# USB/UART connection

Tags: lsusb

I am using a FT232 usb-ttl converter to connect a motorola c115 to DragonOS(Limux). The instruction I use here: . But the cp210x module cannot find the devices, while the lsusb and dmesg commands display the connected converter. Setting the rules didn't help. What actions can I take to gain access to the connected device?

Comment: We only support official Ubuntu. Please use https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for all Linux systems

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.